C++ Rule of Zero with guaranteed/C ABI
I love and often use C++ Rule of Zero, but now there's a use case where I find it challenging to use.
I have 2 libraries, both maintained separately and even compiled with different compilers to different DLLs. One library consumes headers and calls functions of another library. Both are written in C++.
Now, let's say that I need to add a function which receives const data such as an array of strings. In a normal C++ function I'd do:
struct Obj {
    std::vector<std::string> strings;
};

void func(const Obj& obj);

But due to lack of C++ ABI guarantee, I can't do that.
I thought about using std::unique_ptr, but its ABI isn't guaranteed either.
So I can do something like this:
class Obj {
public:
    Obj(std::initializer_list<std::string_view> strings) {
        // Allocate StringsWithAbi and copy strings
    }

    // Rule of Five goes here :(

private:
    struct SymbolString {
        char* string;
        size_t length;
    };

    SymbolString* StringsWithAbi{};
};

void func(const std::vector<std::string> strings);

That requires to resort to Rule of Five and carefully implement copy/move constructors and the rest, which is error prone and just unpleasant boilerplate.
Is there anything simpler I can do? Note that I'd like to be able to use Obj in C++ as well, at least with basic operations such as constructing, moving and copying. And I'd rather not create another copy of it only to call func.
Is there any low-level utility like unique_ptr that has a stable ABI? Any better ideas?

"I have 2 libraries, both maintained separately and even compiled with different compilers": To what degree are the compilers ABI-compatible? If they for example are only compatible with respect to the C core language ABI, then calling any C++ function across the library boundary isn't safe. Or is the core C++ ABI also compatible but just the C++ standard library is not compatible?

If this is only about the standard library, then the solution is of course simple: Implement the library functionality yourself instead of using the standard library or see whether the two compilers can be made to use the same standard library implementation (for example GCC and Clang can both use libstdc++).

I don't know about "calling any C++ function", it worked so far as long as I only use C types, not sure what the standard says. Regarding replacing the whole stdlib, that will work, but too much at this point. My best thought now is to implement a custom my_unique_ptr, then in the second example Obj could have my_unique_ptr instead of the raw pointer, and I won't need the Rule of Five boilerplate. But I hoped the language has something to offer.

The standard has absolutely nothing to say about ABI-compatibility. Thats always completely specific to the compilers in question. Even if you only use C types and such, there is no general reason it should work. Compilers use different C ABIs with e.g. different calling convention on the same architecture. Even if they use the same C ABI specification, there is also the possibility that their core C++ ABIs that extend the C ABIs differ. Even for C types functions may not work because of e.g. different name mangling. It is important what exactly your compilers guarantee.

Reimplementing and using unique_ptr is only safe if the two compilers use the same C and C++ core language ABIs. (That would be for example the case for GCC and Clang on Linux/x86-64, where both use the System V ABI with amd64 supplement as C ABI and the Itanium C++ ABI as C++ ABI. But for example not when comparing MSVC and GCC which use different C++ ABIs and maybe also different C ABIs.)

My project is limited to Windows and I just match the calling convention and export by name of choice, so these already work fine for me. Regarding different C ABIs, I never encountered that, this will mean that it will have a hard time consuming system headers, so I believe C ABI must be compatible.

I don't know much about Windows specifically. There will need to be some compatibility to the system interfaces.

Not what you want, but most likely to get to work would be a C++ wrapper around an interface that uses opaque pointers and "C" functions.  including functions to create and destroy objects. You should be able to get compatible calling conventions and name mangling with this, though you might need explicit specifications for this. Object layout and memory allocation issues restricted to internals of a module that is produced by a single compiler.

I do not know if this is cheating but... why not create a stable ABI utility class and reuse it where appropriate? What you ask for is impossible otherwise to the best of my knowledge.
(Not tested)

template <class T>
class HeapObject;

template<> class HeapObject<void> {
  HeapObject(void * storage) : storage_(storage) {}

  HeapObject(HeapObject && rhs) : storage_(rhs.storage_) {
     rhs.storage_ = nullptr;
  }

  HeapObject & operator=(HeapObject && rhs) {
      storage_ = rhs.storage_;
      rhs.storage_ = nullptr;
      return *this;
  }
  HeapObject & operator=(HeapObject const &) = delete;

protected:
   void * storage_;
};

template <class T>
struct HeapObject : HeapObject<void> {
public:
   T * operator->() {
      return reinterpret_cast<T*>(storage_);
   }

   T const * operator->() const {
      return reinterpret_cast<T*>(storage_);
   }

   T const * operator*() const {
      return reinterpret_cast<T const *>(storage_);
   }

   T * operator*() const {
      return reinterpret_cast<T const *>(storage_);
   }

   ~HeapObject() {
       delete reinterpret_cast<T*>(storage_);
   }
};


struct Obj {
    // This or pimpl
    HeapObject<std::vector<std::string>> vec_{new std::vector<std::string>{}};
};

void func(const Obj& obj);


Thank you, yes, I considered that, but I hoped I can avoid that and use something that's already part of C++. What I ended up doing is using std::unique_ptr, adding static_assert(sizeof(std::unique_ptr) == sizeof(void*));, and relying on it just being the pointer. It's not guaranteed, but it works so far.

Cool. I think that's a good middle point I guess, but I think the cost of authoring a class is lower in the middle term than just relying on non-ABI-safe stuff if that is what you are looking for.

Yes, I'll consider it for longer term. I agree that it's a safer option, but I was looking for something quick and simple. Unfortunately seems that the answer is: there's no such thing in C++.

Since you specifically mention Windows, I hope you are aware of the ABI compatibility in "recent" Visual Studio versions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-170
It basically states that DLLs are forward compatible and can be mixed with DLLs/code compied with more recent versions of the toolset.
Same goes for Clang/GCC really (except for that temporary ABI breakage around C++11's introduction that was fixed in a backwards compatible way eventually).

Thank you, I'm aware, but the project has a component compiled with MSVC and a component compiled with Clang. I understand that my question is quite specific, I hoped that there's something simple in C++ akin to vector.data() which has ABI guarantee. What I ended up doing is using std::unique_ptr, adding static_assert(sizeof(std::unique_ptr) == sizeof(void*));, and relying on it just being the pointer. It's not guaranteed, but it works so far.

Did you compile with clang-cl? In that case, Clang tries to be ABI compatible with MSVC (it is mostly but there are weird edge-cases where it isn't), and it also links with the same C++ standard library as MSVC, which is the most important bit here.
